# Wire Halloween Wolf to howl with Arduino motion detector

Tags: arduino-uno

I bought one of those Home Depot halloween wolves that howl. You can control it with a push-button to be on, or off. It has its own power source via 3 AA batteries that power the howl sound, red eyes and move the jaw.

I'd like to make it motion sensing using the Arduino motion detector.

I thought that I could just cut and splice the wires connecting the button to the wolf to Arduino leads, then use digitalWrite to turn it on/off based on distance detection but it's not working.

The motion detection is working fine, as I set it up like the motion alarm demo. A red LED lights up at the correct distance as well.

Arduino Setup:
pin 10 to J14
J16 to negative

E14 to wolf
E16 to wolf

I'm not sure which wolf wire is +/- so I've tried both

Code:

```
const int trigPin = 11;           //connects to the trigger pin on the distance sensor
const int echoPin = 12;           //connects to the echo pin on the distance sensor

const int redPin = 3;             //pin to control the red LED inside the RGB LED
const int wolfPin = 10;         //pin that will turn on the wolf

float distance = 0;               //stores the distance measured by the distance sensor

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin (9600);        //set up a serial connection with the computer

  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);   //the trigger pin will output pulses of electricity
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);    //the echo pin will measure the duration of pulses coming back from the distance sensor

  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(wolfPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  distance = getDistance();   //variable to store the distance measured by the sensor

  if (distance <= 24) {

    analogWrite(3, 255);
    digitalWrite(wolfPin, HIGH);
    delay(5000);                  

    digitalWrite(wolfPin, LOW);
    delay(1000);
  } else {
    analogWrite(3, 0);
  }

  delay(50);
}
```

I know there's possibility one/both of my spliced wires aren't working, but I don't think so - I'm new, so it's most likely I have so lack of understanding on something.

Please help, Halloween is approaching...

Comment: You need to reverse engineer how the button is wired in the wolf to some degree. Controlling the wolf is certainly possible with the arduino, but you can't randomly connect  wires and buttons and axpect it to work.

Comment: bridge the button with relay contacts

Comment: I agree with @jsotola. I think you can also use a small signal transistor for this. Like the 2n2222a, and wire the base pin of the transistor to your gpio "wolfPin".

Comment: @SimSon I agree with you, please do a electrical schemat of the wolf so you can make right decision for how to control it. To just randomly connect wires is often the cause for fires and smoke ;-)

Comment: By the way, cool project, check in on Arduino "touch sensor" feature, then you can add other cool effects.